# Using Laptop with HDD Inside When Moving in Car

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, storage

I have recently read that modern hard disk drives dislike any kind of vibrations.

So my answer is: is it possible to use a laptop with an HDD inside it without any negative consequences when moving in a car? I have to say that roads in Russia are very, very bad.

What may happen to such storage? Can I minimize impact?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Most laptops that use a traditional HDD use HDDs that have features that are implemented so vibrations are not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDD's don't like vibrations because they have platters inside them spinning extremely fast with tiny magnetic 'heads' that are reading/writing the data to/from the platters. If a vibration with enough G force knocks the 'head' just right, it can 'crash' (see [`head crash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_crash)); if a head crash occurs you can almost guarantee you won't be able to get the data back without some sophisticated tools.

For 'mobile' applications of hard drives, you could get an SSD ([solid state drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)) since, as the name implies, there is no moving parts in the drive (hence solid state) and the G load is a moot issue.

If you can't spare to get an SSD, you can look into some possible [hard drive shock protection](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=hard+drive+shock+protection) applications; there are also 'ruggedized' computer cases that include rubber grommets and other things that help to reduce the total shock to the hard drive.

If you don't want to run a computer with a hard drive you could grab a large enough USB thumb drive (or SD/compact flash/etc) and grab your favorite Live version of Linux or Windows, in which case you don't have to worry about vibrations.

Hope that can help

Answer (score 1):

SSD is fine.

Desktop Spinning Hard Disk Drive, not good.

Laptop Spinning Hard Disk Drives, more resilient than desktop spinning hard disk drives.

Reason is that spinning hard disk drives have moving parts. SSDs don't.

SSD is the modern. So, if anything, modern ones in that sense(not damaged from vibration) are better.
But, with any components, people often find that modern ones don't last as long as ones years ago.